# Jasmine/Javascript - why is a DOM element only accessible by reference from within an async then()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine

After a loooot of testing... I stumbled upon some interesting behavior that I don't understand.

Code:

```
function someFunction() {
  ... // whatever this is stubbed
}

// below is called ("mounted") by finalDOM.mountUserActions()     
$("#button").click(function() {
  savedElement = $("#saved_element")
  console.log("BEFPRE THEN in event listener ==========")
  console.log("found saved_element? = " + savedElement.length)
  console.log("found unsaved_element? = " + $("#unsaved_element").length)

  someFunction().then(function(result){
    console.log("INSIDE THEN in event listener ==========")
    savedElement.val(result)
    $("#unsaved_element").val(result)
    console.log("ensure result is found = " + result)
    console.log("found saved_element? = " + savedElement.length)
    console.log("found unsaved_element?  = " + $("#unsaved_element").length)
  })
})
```

Test code:

```
fdescribe("on click of button", function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    response = Promise.resolve("test")
    spyOn(window, "someFunction").and.returnValue(response)
    savedElement = affix("#saved_element")
    affix("#unsaved_element")
    affix("#button")
    finalDOM.mountUserActions();
    $("#button").click()
  })
  it("should change value of saved_element", function() {
    response.then(function() {
        console.log("INSIDE SPEC EXPECTATION ==========")
        console.log("value of saved_element = " + savedElement.val())
        console.log("value of unsaved_element = " + $("#unsaved_element").val())
      expect(savedElement.val()).toEqual("test") // PASS
      expect($("#unsaved_element").val()).toEqual("test") // FAIL
    })
  })
})
```

Console output:

```
BEFPRE THEN in event listener ==========
found saved_element? = 1
found unsaved_element? = 1
INSIDE THEN in event listener ==========
ensure result is found = test
found saved_element? = 1
found unsaved_element?  = 0
INSIDE SPEC EXPECTATION ==========
value of saved_element = test
value of unsaved_element = undefined
```

The fact that the length of both elements are 1 in `BEFORE THEN in event listener` proves that the affix worked, both elements are on the page, so then why is only the saved element found once `INSIDE THEN in event listener`?

I don't think I've ever encountered this... is this a Javascript gotcha or a Jasmine one? Would love to learn more about it to avoid this in the future... have spent a lot of time scratching my head on it.

Comment: What happens if you comment out `$("#unsaved_element").val(result)`?  Are you even returning a value from someFunction() that can be passed to the callback? it's probably setting it to null.

Comment: 1: Your `#saved_element` isn't really *found* inside the `then` callback, you're storing a reference to it in a variable. When you have this reference you'll have access to it even if it has been removed from the DOM. 2: Your test relies on a promise being resolved, but you haven't written the test accommodate for the fact that it's async. This means that some "post-test" code might run before your `then` callback runs. Maybe this is what happens and this post-test code removes the `#unsaved_element`?

Comment: @Lennholm 1: sure yes I get this fact, but it's still really weird that `#unsaved_element` isn't found. The test has a `response.then` to accommodate the fact that it's async. And if you look at the console output, you'll see that the order is correct, i.e., the entire event listener is called BEFORE the expectations are checked. If the `response.then` were not there, then the first expectation would also fail and the console log would show in this order: 1) `BEFORE THEN` , 2) `INSIDE SPEC`, 3) `INSIDE THEN`

Comment: @womp if I comment it out, the test will definitely fail because then nothing is getting set... but to your point, I put in a `console.log` to check the value of `result` and it in fact is `test`, the `spy.returnValue` is working appropriately

Comment: The most trivial explanation would be that `someFunction()` removes the `#unsaved_element` from the page?

Comment: @james I'm not talking about the order of which **your** test code runs. I'm talking about the fact that Jasmine doesn't know that your test has a promise in it, thus, Jasmine is unaware that it needs to wait before proceeding from your test to the next or with any kind of cleanup. This means that Jasmine might execute some kind of cleanup **before** your `then` block is executed. In other words, your `then` block is still executed, but Jasmine has already moved on. You tell Jasmine that your test is async by using the `done` function and then tell Jasmine the test is done by invoking it.

Comment: @Bergi `someFunction` doesn't do anything (literally)

Comment: @Lennholm I thought that was the purpose of using `response.then(function()` in the expectation block? If not, can you provide your use of `done` in this case in an answer and I can try it out?

Comment: @james Lennholm sounds reasonable. Try to `return` the promise that `.then(…)` creates from the `it` callback - assuming that Jasmine is promise-aware?

Comment: @Bergi, can you please provide an answer with the code example?

Comment: @james Sorry, i don't know Jasmine well enough

Comment: @james The suggestion by Bergi (return the promise) works if you're using Jasmine 2.7 or newer, otherwise you'd have to use the aforementioned `done` function. Have a look here: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async . The examples use the `beforeEach()` function but the same goes for the test functions themselves, i.e. the `it()` function. In short, define your test like this: `it("should change value of saved_element", function(done) { ` and then put `done();` after your last expectation.

Comment: I definitely tried that and it didn't work... Sorry I just saw this comment